# why the value is 24 for buffer1[5]

Tags: c

I am working buffer overflow problem and want to try an example from this page. http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

### I tried this:

```
int function(int a, int b, int c) {
   char buffer1[5];
}

void main() {
  function(1,2,3);
}
```

---

when I run gcc -S -o example1.s example1.c and I found this in the example1.s, why the value is $24 here?

```
function:
        pushl %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp
        subl $24, %esp
        leave
        ret
```

Red Hat Linux 3.2.2-5 
gcc version 3.2.2
cpu mode: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q9650

Comment: Keep in mind that modern compilers will put in protection against simple buffer overflow attacks into your code

Comment: @Puciek: Still, 24 bytes for a 5 byte variable seems a bit excessive.

Comment: What compiler?  What processor?  What OS?  Side note: `int main` not `void main`.  I wonder why so many people get this wrong?

Comment: @JohnZwinck because that is what they teach in schools :)

Comment: @Puciek: my school taught the correct form more than a decade ago.  Did all the professors who knew C die off?

Comment: The first book I read to learn C used `void main()` -- it was written at least twenty years ago.  Of all the opportunities to shoot yourself in the foot with C, `int main` vs `void main` hardly seems like a worthy nit to pick.

Comment: You haven't asked the compiler to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

this is because of stack alignment.  by default, gcc aligns the stack on 16-byte boundaries.  check the gcc -mpreferred-stack-boundary option to change the stack boundary value.

the stack already contains 8 bytes for the leave and ret addresses.  So to align the "buffer1" local, another 8 bytes are added.  then, "buffer1" takes another 16 bytes block, which gives you the 24 "magic number".